# Burninate [2] job tag

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs, advertising

This [job offer](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/89074/requ%C3%AAteur-d%C3%A9veloppeur-java-sql-f-h-orange) includes the tag [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/2).

[image]

It seems to be a mistake and looks unclean to me.

What can we do about it?

Comment: sounds to me like an "arrondissement". France uses numbers to specify certain regions. I don't know if it's a tag or not, but I'd assume the guy is in the "deuxieme arrondissement"

Comment: BURN THE UNCLEAN!

Comment: Noisy-le-Grand? The big noisy?

Comment: There is one more tag \[[1\]](http://stackoverflow.com/jobs?tags=1)

Comment: I've removed the [burninate-request] tag from here, as this concerns SO jobs which isn't a part of the public SO tags. Lemme know if you disagree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for letting us know! You can do this here, or by flagging the listing on Careers. We've updated the tags, and will get with the client to see what might have happened and help them do better next time.

Comment: This happened again: https://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/90879/concepteur-d%C3%A9veloppeur-informatique-f-h-orange. I've flagged it.